# using The same RecyclerView for two Tabs in android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment, toolbar

I have a `RecyclerView` and two `Tab`s in my `MainActivity`. I just want to show another data in RecyclerView when each Tab gets selected. for doing this should I use ViewPager for Tabs? should I use Fragment? I really don't know. Are they needed in my example? the only difference between tabs is just the data they show to user inside RecylerView. `RecyerView` is the same. `Toolbar` is the same , etc. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off yes you will need a `ViewPager`. This `ViewPager` will require you to use `Fragments`. [Take a look at this example from the official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral).

To solve your `RecyclerView` problem you have two options:

- define a custom `RecyclerView` (by extending Androids RecyclerView)
- defining a custom `RecyclerViewAdapter` and use it with a `RecyclerView`

I would advise you to do the first if the RecyclerViews are completely similar. Then you could define all your properties with it, without having to do that twice in your Tab Fragment. Otherwise take the second option.

Comment: shouldn't  I use just a TabLayout? Fragment and ViewPager is necesarry? I do not want to have two page and bacause of that I think Fragment and ViewPager is not necessary. is it?

Comment: Well you cant really use a TabLayout without Fragments

Comment: Please look at this http://www.dominoc925.blogspot.com/2016/05/using-android-xml-layout-tabs-without.html?m=1

Comment: I understand where he is coming from. He just adds a listener to the TabLayout, then when a Tab is clicked you could theoretically set the different data to your RecyclerView. Note that you have to either create a new Adapter (if the same one is required this is not an issue) or call notifyDatasetChanged() on it after setting the new items.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using Conductor?

[Conductor](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor)

[Why I choose Conductor over Fragment?](https://dev.to/chingiz/why-i-choose-conductor-over-fragment--4b5b)

It is a cool replacement for Fragments.